# Give an example of a function with singularity at $0$ and whose contour integral is zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of a function that has a singularity at $0$ and whose contour integral around the circle $|z|=1$ is zero. Explain briefly why.

Need help verifying my example.

Example:

$f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z}$

For $\oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z}$,

we have a singularity at $0$.

So the residue of $f$ at $z=0$ of order $1$ is:

Res($f(z),z=0$) $= \displaystyle{\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}} \frac{d}{dz} \cos(z) = \displaystyle{\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}}-\sin(z) = -\sin(0) = 0$.

The value of the integral in the positive direction:

$\Rightarrow 2\pi i(0) = 0$.

The function has one pole at $z=0$, so any closed contour integral around the origin, namely the circle $|z|=1$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the residue is wrong, should be no derivation there, its just $Res_0(f)=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0}z\cdot f(z)$ for a singularity of first order. Alternative ways are using the fact that $\cos(z)=1+z^2/2+...$, therefore your function can be written as $\frac{1}{z}+...$ where the dots represent the remaining, non-fractional parts of the series. As the rest of the series is analytical and therefore holomorphic, it's contour integral is 0, so you just have the contour integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ left, which is $2\pi i$.

Comment: For singularities of first order you can also use $Res_a f=\frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}$ for $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$.

Comment: If you still need an example for a function with singularity at 0 and contour integral 0, just take $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$. You can argue either with the formula for higher-order singularities or that the Laurent expansion around 0 is already given by the function as it is and as the Laurent coefficient for $\frac{1}{z}$ is the residue, it is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)$ be represented by its Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ in the annulus $r<|z|<R$, where $r<1<R$.

If $a_{-1}=0$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=1}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n\,dz\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\oint_{|z|=1}z^n\,dz\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, any function whose Laurent series representation has $a_{-1}=0$, will suffice.  If $a_{-k}\ne 0$ for some $k\ge 2$, then $f(z)$ has a singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a function $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\},$ with an isolated singularity at $0,$ such that $f$ has an antiderivative in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$ If you have this, then the integral of $f$ over any closed contour in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ is $0$ simply by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

An example is $f(z) = 1/z^2,$ which has the antiderivative $-1/z$ in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$